# KeyListener won't do anything

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I'm trying to add a keylistener to JFrame but whenever I click a button, nothing happens. I am trying to get the keylistener to just print something basic but whenever i try to use an if statement nothing happens in the console.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class KeyListener implements java.awt.event.KeyListener {

ArrayList <JButton> _buttons;
JFrame _frame1;

public KeyListener(ArrayList <JButton> buttons, JFrame frame1){
    _buttons = buttons;
    _frame1 = frame1;
    _frame1.addKeyListener(this);
    _frame1.requestFocusInWindow();
    _frame1.setFocusable(true);
    this.keyTyped();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

        System.out.println("yes");
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

That is my keylistener class

This is my game class

```
package model;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Game implements Runnable{

KeyListener _keylistener;

@Override
public void run() {
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("KeyBricks");
    frame1.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();


    frame1.addKeyListener(_keylistener);
    model.Board board = new model.Board(panel1);

    frame1.add(panel1);

    frame1.pack();

    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

}
```

Comment: Try adding it to the `panel` not the `frame`

Comment: I don't see the difference that would make

Comment: Well try it out and see :P

Comment: JPanel _panel1;
 
 public KeyListener(ArrayList <JButton> buttons, JPanel panel1){
  _buttons = buttons;
  _panel1 = panel1;
  _panel1.addKeyListener(this);
     _panel1.requestFocusInWindow();
     _panel1.setFocusable(true);
     
 }
The same results came out as before

Comment: Oh i see your problem... you have the wrong `KeyListener` imported silly. In your game class you have `import java.awt.event.KeyListener;` it should be `import gui.KeyListener` (Your custom class)

Comment: Your `_keylistener` variable is `null` (test it if you don't believe me, or show me where you initialize it to an object)! But regardless, just like most of the similar questions, don't use a KeyListener, use Key Bindings.

Comment: Thank you for helping but I still can't get it to work, I just changed it to gui.KeyListener.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how would i change it from null? I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`, it's problemmatic at best. Use the Key Bindings API instead.  [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Try not to name classes with the same name ... which `KeyListener` is which?

Comment: You're also (if `_keyListener` wasn't `null`) double registering the `KeyListener`, which would result in you been notified twice

Comment: This is for a cs class so I have to use KeyListener :(. and I'll change it thank you for the help but I got it to work <3

Comment: `"how would i change it from null?"` You assign it a new object, something you're not doing. You've simply declared the variable and have assigned it nothing as yet.

Comment: ok, I have a problem again. This works in the keyPressed method but not in keyTyped and when I click on it, it prints out yes twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could register a [KeyEventDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html):

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("dispatchKeyEvent: "+e);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that the registered KeyEventDispatchers will receive KeyEvents **before** they are dispatched to their targets, allowing to retarget the event, consume it, dispatch the event itself, or make other changes.